# The find element returns empty string..using XPath contains,Text()

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

The assertion fails as the Gender and date returns false.The IwebElement returns an element but when I print the text in it.The result is an empty string.This happens only for Gender and Date rest all give correct result.

**CODE**

```
 IWebElement actualname = BrowserHelper.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'"+ name+"')]"));
            Console.Write(actualname.Text);
            IWebElement actualIdentifier = BrowserHelper.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(text(),'"+ Identifier+"')]"));
            Console.Write(actualIdentifier.Text);
            IWebElement actualGender = BrowserHelper.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(text(),'"+ Gender+"')]"));
             Console.Write(actualGender.Text);
            IWebElement actualDateofBirth = BrowserHelper.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(text(),'"+ DateofBirth+"')]"));
            Console.Write(actualDateofBirth.Text);
            IWebElement actualAddress = BrowserHelper.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(text(),'"+ Address+"')]"));
            Console.Write(actualAddress.Text);

            Assert.IsTrue((actualname.Displayed) && (actualIdentifier.Displayed) && (actualGender.Displayed) && (actualDateofBirth.Displayed) && (actualAddress.Displayed), "Incorrect out put displayed for patient query");
```

**HTML**:-

```html
<tbody _ngcontent-c32="" style="max-height: 20vh;">
            <!----><tr _ngcontent-c32="">
              <td _ngcontent-c32="" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:5em">
                <input _ngcontent-c32="" type="checkbox" id="0_checkbox">
              </td>
              <td _ngcontent-c32="" style="vertical-align:middle">
                <!----><span _ngcontent-c32="" class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                <a _ngcontent-c32="" href="javascript:void(0)">Braden Dunthorn</a>
              </td>
              <td _ngcontent-c32="" style="vertical-align:middle">Tribal ID: 49963093</td>
              <td _ngcontent-c32="" style="vertical-align:middle">M</td>
              <td _ngcontent-c32="" style="vertical-align:middle">12/21/1990</td>
              <td _ngcontent-c32="" style="vertical-align:middle">7 Carioca , Grenville, MD, 29605</td>
              <!---->
            </tr><tr _ngcontent-c32="">
              <td _ngcontent-c32="" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:5em">
```

Answer (score 0):

A blind guess but judging from my own experience, maybe there is a reason these two fields load *later* than others (for example, lazy loading?). Consider setting up a wait of 1 second (pretty large wait time, I know, but you can always lower it down after you find if it works).

Expanding on the comment, I would try something like this (pseudocode-ish):

```
new Thread(()=>{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    IWebElement actualGender = BrowserHelper.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(text(),'"+ Gender+"')]"));
    Console.Write(actualGender.Text);
    //put a breakpoint here to look at the value received
}).Start();
```

And last attempt: try getting all `td` elements `BrowserHelper.WebDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//td"))`. Is Gender element in this list?

Comment: I doubt Thread.Sleep would do any difference because it stops the main thread. Can you try to access this data from another thread using Thread.Sleep in it?

Comment: I do not understand.Could you please explain? how access from another thread?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Is that your requirement to search by text?

Because here you are searching by element containing text 'M'

```
//td[contains(text(),'"+ Gender+"')]"
```

This will return two elements since both these contain text 'M'

```
<td _ngcontent-c32="" style="vertical-align:middle">M</td>
<td _ngcontent-c32="" style="vertical-align:middle">7 Carioca , Grenville, MD, 29605</td>
```

I would recommend to change your approach to use other locators (I guess xpath axes can help). If you know one element lets say id and location of gender, dob is static then xpath axes is best approach.

Comment: the table being created is dynamic and does not have ID.Searching for M should return displayed as it tries to catch first appearance. But even if your logic is true but then why same thing is happening with date?
Co-incidently these are the two elements which have different data type in DB. Gender=char and date=datetime.

Answer (score 0):

For the unmatched *XPath* for *Gender* and *DateofBirth* you can use the following solutions:

- *Gender*:

  ```
  IWebElement actualGender = BrowserHelper.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[normalize-space()='" + Gender + "']"));
  ```
- *DateofBirth*:

  ```
  IWebElement actualDateofBirth = BrowserHelper.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[normalize-space()='" + DateofBirth + "']"));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try fetching the `innerText` attribute to get the required text, as shown below:

```
IWebElement actualDateofBirth = BrowserHelper.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(text(),'"+ DateofBirth+"')]"));
Console.Write(actualDateofBirth.GetAttribute("innerText"));
```

Let me know, whether it works for you.